# Jetty : with two or more IP addresses, how to add another SSL connector?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Using Jetty 9.4 on Windows

For http, whenever having another IP address, I just copy the jetty-http.xml to etc folder and edit the file to have another connector with everything else the same except the IP address as below example (in this case my IPs are 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5)

```
<Call name="addConnector">
<Arg>
  <New id="httpConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptors" deprecated="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.selectors" deprecated="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
            <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
            <Arg name="compliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.http.compliance" default="RFC7230"/></Arg></Call></Arg>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
    <Set name="host">1.2.3.4</Set>
    <Set name="port">80</Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.http.idleTimeout" deprecated="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
    <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.http.soLingerTime" deprecated="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="http.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

```
<Call name="addConnector">
<Arg>
  <New id="httpConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptors" deprecated="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.selectors" deprecated="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
            <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
            <Arg name="compliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.http.compliance" default="RFC7230"/></Arg></Call></Arg>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
    <Set name="host">1.2.3.5</Set>
    <Set name="port">80</Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.http.idleTimeout" deprecated="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
    <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.http.soLingerTime" deprecated="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="http.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

However, for https. When I do the same for file ssl-jetty.xml as below

```
  <Call  name="addConnector">
<Arg>
  <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <!-- uncomment to support proxy protocol
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
        </Item>-->
      </Array>
    </Arg>

    <Set name="host">1.2.3.4</Set>
    <Set name="port">443</Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
    <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

```
<Call  name="addConnector">
<Arg>
  <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <!-- uncomment to support proxy protocol
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
        </Item>-->
      </Array>
    </Arg>

    <Set name="host">1.2.3.5</Set>
    <Set name="port">443</Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
    <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

getting this exception as below. Not sure whats missing here?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No protocol factory for default protocol: null
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1516)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a Jetty expert; however, I have recently struggled with the same problem you appear to have.  I can offer what I've done to eliminate the protocol issue, but I expect this will only get you to the next stage of problems (keystore/certificate).  Your exception, "No protocol factory for default protocol: null", indicates your new connector doesn't reference a ContextFactory, which in turn should specify the protocol.  So, without specifying a protocol, you're assigning it as null.  Although, I don't understand why the original SSL connector you copied didn't cause the same issue, as it doesn't appear to reference an sslContextFactory id.

Within the parent server config, you should see a SslContextFactory.  If it's there, copy/past, changing it's id uniquely, and ensure the protocol is set appropriately.  My Jetty classes are unique to my application, but you should be able to take what I have with some minor changes according to Eclipse.org for Jetty classes, and get past the protocol problem, and on to the next.

Within the server config, your sslContextFactory should look similar to this:

```
<New id="secondarySSLContextFactory" class="com.myapp.appserver.jetty.server.connector.ssl.RuntimeSslContextFactory">
    <Set name="renegotiationAllowed">true</Set>
    <Set name="needClientAuth">false</Set>
    <Set name="wantClientAuth">false</Set>
    <Set name="protocol">TLS</Set>
    <Set name="secureRandomAlgorithm">SHA1PRNG</Set>
    <Set name="excludeProtocols">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <!-- Excluded to mitigate POODLE attack -->
            <Item>SSLv3</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</New>
```

Then your newly modified connector would then be similar to:

```
<Call  name="addConnector">
<Arg>
  <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <!-- uncomment to support proxy protocol
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
        </Item>-->
        <!-- REFERENCE TO CONTEXT FACTORY ID -->
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
            <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
            <Arg name="sslContextFactory">
              <Ref refid="secondarySSLContextFactory"/>
            </Arg>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>

    <Set name="host">1.2.3.5</Set>
    <Set name="port">443</Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
    <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
    <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

Additionally, if you expect to use an alternate SSL cert for the alternate IP, you'll have to build a new keystore.  The above secondarySSLContextFactory is where the new keystorepath and password are set.  There are many references to help with that.  However, beyond creating and assigning a new cert+chain/keystore, I have little helpful experience making the server use them, but the new connector will respond.  I've found nothing to help with that in Jetty 9.  I Hope what I've provided helps somewhat.